# Kusto tabular arguments with multiple columns

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

How do I properly define and invoke a user function with an argument of tabular type which has multiple columns?

This page does not have any examples of that sort - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/functions/user-defined-functions#features-that-are-currently-unsupported-by-user-defined-functions

To provide some context for my question, here is my attempt for doing this

```
let foo=(T1:(col1:string, col2:string))
{
    T1|count // something more complex will go here,
             // so just avoiding the whole function is not an option.
}
someTable | summarize Res=foo(Col1, Col2) by Col3, Col4
```

Here Kusto recognizes my function, but complains about it accepting only one argument.
How can I go about passing two columns to it?

Thanks,
Dusan

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. Can you please provide sample input (in datatable format) and expected output? Then ping here and we'll try to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, you cannot invoke a user-defined function as a summarize function, the list of summarization functions is defined by the Kusto Query Language and currently cannot be extended.

Within a query, a function that accepts a tabular input can only be invoked using the [invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/invokeoperator) operator